# Spring JDBC Template - Oracle DB Function returns null

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-jdbc

I have my Oracle DB Stored Function as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FN_EMP_CNT (EMP_ID NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER
IS
  OLD_COUNT NUMBER(5) DEFAULT 0;
  NEW_COUNT NUMBER(5) DEFAULT 0;
BEGIN

  SELECT
    COUNT(EMP_ID) INTO OLD_COUNT
  FROM
    OLD_DEPT
  WHERE
    EID = EMP_ID
    AND DEPT_STAT='Closed';
  SELECT
    COUNT(EMP_ID) INTO NEW_COUNT
  FROM
    NEW_DEPT
  WHERE
    EID = EMP_ID
    AND DEPT_STAT='Closed'
  RETURN (NEW_COUNT + OLD_COUNT);
END;
```

When I use the below sql query directly it returns the correct number as 2:

```
SELECT FN_EMP_CNT(123) FROM DUAL;
```

But when I use Spring JDBC Template for retrieving the data it returns **null**.

```
int noOfEmps = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT FN_EMP_CNT(?) FROM DUAL", new Object[] { empID}, Integer.class);
```

Comment: are you shure that the program is in the same schema as the function?

Comment: Yes they are referring to the same schema.

Comment: I'm not an expert at this, but why are you passing an args array when you don't have any bind variables in your sql statement? Have you tried `queryForObject("SELECT FN_EMP_CNT(123) FROM DUAL", Integer.class)`?

Comment: sorry its a typo, updated the query. Actually we are binding the employee id to the function.

Comment: To troubleshoot further, I'd suggest changing the function to just `return 2;` and see if that works. Or try changing your query to "SELECT ? FROM DUAL" to make sure your bind variable works.

Comment: @kfinity the problem was not in the SQL but in the parameters of `queryForObject`see update below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most probable cause is that you use a wrong order of parameters, see Javadoc [queryForObject](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html)

```
queryForObject(java.lang.String sql, java.lang.Class<T> requiredType, java.lang.Object... args)
Query given SQL to create a prepared statement from SQL and a list of 
 arguments to bind to the query, expecting a result object.
```

So use first the required return type followed by the parameter

This works for my fine

```
sql = 'SELECT FN_EMP_CNT(?) FROM DUAL'
res = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, Integer.class, 4)
```

HTH